# Select row for each worksheet with activecell

Tags: excel, vba

I need a small loop that cuts a row and inserts it at the row 2 for every worksheet.
The entire row should be detected or selected by only selecting a single cell in the first column.

I've tried adding a simple for each to the code (see below) but it end up sorting the every row by date.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut
    Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next 
End Sub
```

It should move the entire row, in every worksheet, to the top of the list by only selecting a cell and pressing the commandbutton in the first worksheet.

The entire row should be detected or selected by only selecting a single cell in the first column.

If someone could also explain how to work with Activevell and a loop through every worksheet that would be nice as well.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me. Do you want to paste the line from one worksheet to multiple sheets, or do you want to cut the same rownumber on all sheets and put in on row two?

Comment: Second suggestion mate. Cut the same row number in all the sheet by only selecting a cell in the first sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the bare minimum of code you are trying to use would look like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut
    ws.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next ws

End Sub
```

This would loop through all elements (sheets) in the [sheets collection of the current workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheets). Activecell is a reference to the focussed cell currently displayed on the active sheet, the sheet as where you press the commandbutton (assumed) as per your statement:

> *"It should move the entire row, in every worksheet, to the top of the list **by only selecting a cell and pressing the commandbutton in the first worksheet**."*

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of For Each loop, that's why I'm using just for next loop :)

I think it should be useful :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim numb As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim pos As Integer

numb = Application.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To numb

    With Sheets(i)
        .Select
        pos = ActiveCell.Row
        .Rows(pos).Cut
        .Rows(2).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End With

Next i

End Sub
```

If You still need answer for your last sentence add a comment, hope it helps :)